# tomcat7 vs. tomcat6, Is there any significant difference in their performance?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat6, tomcat7, stress-testing

I have been working on stress testing a Java web application (JSP+Tomcat6+Struts2+Hibernate+mysql) and well the results I was getting wasn't something to brag about! So I upgraded the tomcat version to 7, and wow! the requests/sec I got was 5 times better than before.

So enlighten me, is there this much difference between tomcat6 and tomcat7's performance? or there is something wrong with my configuration and stuff?

Answer (score 9):

The Tomcat ["Which Version"](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) page includes a high level overview of the differences between different Tomcat versions.  The section for Tomcat 7.x does not claim massive performance increases for Tomcat 7.x versus Tomcat 6.x.  A Google search didn't offer any clear evidence either.

I'd be inclined to think that a 5-fold throughput improvement is either:

- a Java / Tomcat configuration and/or tuning issue,
- something a bit unusual about your web application, or
- an unidentified artefact of the way you are doing your performance measurements.

Answer (score 7):

What is the difference between Tomcat 7.0 and Tomcat 6.0?

- Tomcat 7.0 has improved  the security over Tomcat 6.0 due to several security code fixes and additions (such as CSRF prevention filter).
- Tomcat 7.0 includes Servlet 3.0 API, which it self is an improved version over its previous version (used by Tomcat 6.0).
- So, 3rd party applications that need Servlet 3 containers are supported by Tomcat 7.0.
- Configurability is better in Tomcat 7.0, which includes new container components (e.g. ExpiresFilter and AddDefaultCharsetFilter) that allow better handling of problems previously left to the web applications to resolve.
- Tomcat 7.0 supports Java 6 or further version, while Tomcat 6.0 supports Java 5 or further version.
- Finally, Tomcat 7.0 includes cleaner and modernized code that uses generics in the required places.

Comment: Not true. Tomcat6 support jdk7 as well.

Comment: @vsingh - "supports Java 6 and later" >>means<< "supports Java 6, and Java 7, and Java 8, and ......"